# Trying to find a font I used previously

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to identify a font that I used on a past project. I did try font finding services but didn't get a match. When I tried WhatTheFont, a key problem was the lack of (or incorrectly shaped) loop on the capital L.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as trying more than one font finder service...

[image]

[Bakery Font on WhatFontIs](https://www.whatfontis.com/FF_Bakery.font?text=ThLichtensteins)

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!